# submit event not firing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to submit a form when changing a drop down menu and want to prevent the page from reloading.

```js
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
$(document).ready( function(){
  $('#adv_search').submit( function(e){
    alert('form submitted');
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```html
<form id="adv_search" name="adv_search" method="post">
  <select name="state" id="state" onchange="document.adv_search.submit()">
    ------
  </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The plain javascript's `submit()` will trigger the natural submit process of a form, you cannot bypass it with a jquery's `submit`. So it is better to use jQuery alone for doing this,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#state").change(function() {
    $('#adv_search').submit();
  });
  $('#adv_search').submit(function(e) {
    alert('form submitted');
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/zhuuczdj/)

Comment: @SanobarShiakh Did you check the demo that i given? And did you read the explanations in this answer?

Comment: yes nd i've also applied it to my code. bt m getting $_post array null.

Comment: @SanobarShiakh Did you remove the inline handler from `select` element? In the html code.

Comment: @SanobarShiakh Can you reproduce your issue in a fiddle?

Comment: i am getting alert message but post array is null.

Comment: @SanobarShiakh That is a new problem, related to server sided code. Probably you have to ask a new question to solve that. I hope i have solved the problem of yours in front end.

Comment: @SanobarShiakh Try to press the tick mark present inside of this answer, If you feel that this answer has helped you solving your front end issues. And this is not a compulsion. :)